# Default case in select statement almost behaves as blocking

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I noticed a weird behavior that is not entirely obvious when using select statement inside a loop, for example if I have:

```
package main


import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("here we go")
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("Bye")
                return
            default:
                fmt.Println("this should continue to print")
            }
            fmt.Println("loop continues")
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    done <- true
}
```

I would assume that the default case should only print for no longer than 2 seconds, however this is not the case, at least in my CPU it is lasting for about 10 seconds before seeing the `Bye` message.

However if I add `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` right after "loop continues" It is more or less in sync with the 2 second sleep before `done <- true`.

Given this my assumption is that print calls are getting stacked and the extended completion time is due to the call stack taking longer to get through.
Is is this a correct description of what's happening? Or am I missing something more obvious.

**Edit:** To put my hypothesis to test I did this and it now works as expected, it takes 2 seconds to finish the program:

```
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("here we go")
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("Bye")
                return
            default:
            }
        }
    }()
```

Comment: Terminal output is probably buffered and you are observing the printing of buffered lines. See how it behaves if you redirect the oitput to a file.

Comment: It never makes sense to have a spinning, unblocked default in a `for { select { ` loop.  I realize your'e just playing with the language here, but you're getting weird behavior because you're not writing good Go.

Comment: I actually got the idea because I saw it being done in the official k8s client-go lib: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/v0.24.0-alpha.0/tools/cache/reflector.go#L398